# Thredds server WMS/Godiva working but WMS link just shows XML

Tags: thredds

I have the latest Thredds server working with Tomcat 7 and in the threddsConfig.XML file I have enabled WMS. This causes the Godiva link to show at the bottom in the Viewers category.

However, above, in the Access category, which now shows both OPENDAP and WMS, the WMS link doesn't work correctly. When the link is clicked, both IE and Chrome just display the XML.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that is the intended response when you click the WMS link on the THREDDS Data Server.  If you examine the URL of that link, you can see that it is a WMS GetCapabilities request, which should look something like:

`http://geoport.whoi.edu/thredds/wms/coawst_4/use/fmrc/coawst_4_use_best.ncd?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities`

The GetCapabilities request returns an XML document describing the capabilities of this particular WMS Service (e.g. which datasets are available, what projections, etc).

This is a required service request for WMS services, and the returned information is used by WMS clients to display valid options to users.